# Strange C++ syntax with square brackets

Tags: c++

I recently came across this code and not certain what it is,

```
    CommClient.MakeHandler<nx::CommError>
(
    [&channel_stats](nx::CommError &c)
    {
        (void)c;
        channel_stats = false;
    }
);
```

Any one knows what this might be?

Thanks

Comment: It is a lambda expression, which were introduced in C++11. See linked duplicate. That is not a particularly strange or uncommon syntax and you will probably see them in most code bases using C++11 or later. They are very helpful, replacing a lot of boilerplate that functors required pre-C++11.

Comment: @pcbGuru It is a function call with an argument that represents a lambda expression.

Comment: What is more peculiar is the `(void)c;` instruction, probably to silence an *unused parameter* warning from the compiler. But the cleanest and easiest way for that would have been to just omit the `c` argument name in the lambda.